# File is not being uploaded in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is very similar to a question I asked recently, which I have since deleted, but I have a better understanding of the issue I'm facing now and believe I could ask a more clear question.

I am creating a file upload application. I am limiting it to only .dem files, which are quite uncommon. I have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to support my file upload, and I have correctly named everything. When I submit my file, it does not seem to be received by the controller.

Here is my code:

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
    @csrf
    <label for="demo" id="drop" class="drop">
         <p>Drag demos here <br>or <span style="color:#2b66cc;">browse</span></p>
    </label>
    <input id="demo" type="file" name="demo" multiple accept=".dem"></input>
    <div id="list" style="cursor:default;" class="ui animated list"></div>
    <button id="submit" class="ui primary fluid button" disabled type="submit">Upload</button><br>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UploadController@store')->name('upload');
```

**Controller**

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->file());
        
    }
}
```

All I'm doing here is just trying to receive the file.

When I run this code and upload a file through the form, $request-file() returns an empty array. This indicates to me that my file never actually reaches the controller for some reason beyond me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `file` requires a parameter which is the name of the input (demo in this case). And if I'm not mistaken you can see all files with `$request->files()`

Comment: Yeah I have tested it using file('demo'). It returns null.

Comment: And what happens when you use `dd` to see the full contents of `$request`? If the file is not there, then there should be a problem with your form. (Maybe the `</input>` is causing problems. Input doesn't have close tag)

Comment: Image [link](https://i.imgur.com/nHzfbZ0.png). Also, I forgot to remove the closing tag, but it isn't what's causing the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Strange. Maybe it is a restriction in size? How big is the file you're trying to upload? And have you tried uploading something without the `accept` attribute and just pick some random image or text file?

Comment: Try removing `multiple` from the file input just to check if that causes any confusion

Comment: I'm uploading a file that's around 20,000KB. I tried it with a 9KB image and the same error. Also tried without `multiple`, same error.

Comment: I have recreated your code locally, for me it works (with a regular PDF file).

First of all, the input tag is self closing so you do not need to close it manually.

Consider removing the `multiple` and `accept` attribute and upload a regular PDF file.

Additionally, change `dd($request->file());` into `dd($request->file('demo'));`

Comment: This is very strange. I have also tried to upload a pdf file and it still didn't work, even with the listed changes.

Comment: How large is your PDF file? What are the sizes of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Did you try removing the ``accept`` attribute?

Comment: `upload_max_filesize=40M`, `post_max_size=40M` - Yes @HéctorWilliam

Comment: What does `dd($request->all());` return for you (inside the store method of your controller)?

Comment: @SimonK `array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "8Fhctgy0RvWA2lPLJq4yyIG5P1S2zrtZzEHRbbxS"
]`

Comment: Try removing all other HTML, so basically all you have left is a page with:

`<form action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="demo" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>`

A shot in the dark: try giving a different URL than just a `/` to your POST route.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input id="demo" type="file" name="demo[]" multiple accept=".dem">
```

when you are uploading multiple files in the INPUT tag
INPUT tag goes in array